# Expected is to actual as expectee to what?

Tags: single-word-requests

> A value that is *expected* might be nounized to an *expectee* awaited by the *expector*.

Is there a formal term corresponding to that for the adjective *actual*?

> A value that is *actual* might be nounized to a *what* received by the *whom*.

My suggestions for *what* are either *actual* or *actuee* and for *whom* they're *actuator* or *actuator*. Am I anywhere close to being correct? Is it understandable to NSEs (if yet a bit artificial and formal)? What'd be a better way to express these formally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actuee and actuator derive from the *verb* **actuate**, which would have **actuated** as its participle. That participle you could use as an adjective.

This can be done for adjectives that are participles of *verbs*, because from *verbs* we can derive nouns that describe the actor and patient of that verb.

However, looking for agents and patients based on random adjectives makes no sense. You may as well ask:

> A value that is **good** might be nounized to a *what* received by the *whom*.
>   A value that is **valid** might be nounized to a *what* received by the *whom*.

You want to introduce a goodee and a gooder? A validee and a valider?

Oh, validator is not correct, it comes from validate! The corresponding question would be:

> A value that is **validated** might be nounized to a *what* received by the *whom*.

Comment: I realize the logical/grammatical inconsistency here. Having said that - *goodee* and *gooder* as deminitives of *benefactor* and *provider* might be cute to use, as an amusement. "Oh, look - there goes my goodee! I've been her gooder for a long time." Not a formal language, though... Why -1, by the way?

Comment: @KonradViltersten - ok, I concede that with _good_ there are options. But don't tell me you consider orangee/oranger, biggee/bigger, minutee/minuter, deadee/deader or superficiallee/superficialler as even remotely plausible or remotely understandable... I would not even _know_ how to describe the effect of a superficialler on a superficiallee :)

Comment: Oh, you're just being **an unwillingee** to my being **plausibler**.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten - that makes you an unwillinger. I'm not sure you want that :D